# Call a function in add_rewrite_rule?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a specific URL-function that returns proper pretty URLs for my own plugin that I want to use for 301-redirecting.

So what I need to do is take

> /groups/123_ABC

and pass

> 123

into my function

> getPrettyURL(123)

So I thought I could do:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^/groups/(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$', getPrettyURL($matches[1]), 'top');
```

but that does not work. What's wrong?

Comment: mismatched parentheses maybe?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo here on SO only...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Rewrite API provided by WordPress; I see that you don't want the leading `/` in your regex.

Try

```
add_rewrite_rule('^groups/(\d+)[_a-zA-Z]+/?$', getPrettyURL($matches[1]), 'top');
```

Comment: thanks! But it does just nothing, when it should redirect me to the URL returned by getPrettyURL... and I'd also have to add http 301, which is easy in htaccess direct but with the WP-function?

Comment: I mean the purpose is not to rewrite, but to redirect - so if someone calls /groups/123_ABC he should be redirected to the URL returned by my function...

Comment: I think you'd want to use [`wp_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect). I have no knowledge of WordPress API. Perhaps, you should ask a moderator to move the question to [wordpress.se].